# Second to_replace to dataframe is not updating dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am replacing values of an existing dataframe in Python during a `for loop`.  My original dataframe is of this format:

[image]

After trying to update the items in the "slice_file_name" and "fsID" via these pandas replace commands:

```
df1['slice_file_name'] = df1['slice_file_name'].replace(to_replace=str(row["slice_file_name"]),value=f'{actual_filename}_{directory}.wav')

fsID_Name = str(row["fsID"])

df1['fsID'] = df1['fsID'].replace(to_replace=str(row["fsID"]), value=f'{fsID_Name}_{directory}')
```

Only the "slice_file_name" gets updated correctly:

[image]

The "fsID" does not get updated correctly.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I want to update the "fsID" column as follows: - for example for the first data row, "fsID" should be equal to 102305_TimeShift-10pct.  I see from my ide that `f'{fsID_Name}_{directory}'` gives the correct string, but it is not updating the fsID cell.  How to update the fsID cell accordingly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are looking for 'fsID', would this work (after your 'slice_file_name' is updated) ?

```
df['fsID']=df['fsID']+'_'+df['slice_file_name'].str.split('_',expand=True)[1].str.replace('.wav','')
```